# need help to find Xpath of following html--selenium--

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I am using firebug for finding xpath, this is the error that is displayed in the error console.

> no such element: Unable to locate
>   element:{"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='select2-contact_id-result-v0w5-258']"}

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='select2-contact_id-result-v0w5-258']")).click();
```

html is as follow

```
id="select2-contact_id-result-v0w5-258" class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Single contact
```

Comment: you'll need to give us more html than the attributes of one element.  with what you've given us so far, my only guess is that there's a timing issue (the object hasn't appeared yet) or it's inside an iframe.

Comment: Actually  there are two dependent searchable dropdown. one is depend on other.. if we search and select the company from 1st drop down.then in 2nd dropdown we have contact of the selected company. in 2nd dropdown we have to search and select a contact.. I have searched the contact but its Xpath is not clickable as the error say..

Comment: So, if you show us some more of your code, perhaps we can help you determine where the problem lies.  again, a wild guess would be that the code to do the first step didn't do it's job correctly, leaving the second step broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be following reason for it :-

- May be your `id` is dynamically generated, so you need to try with different locator to create `By` object as below

  ```
  By by = By.className("select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted");
  ```

  or

  ```
  By by = By.cssSelector(".select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted");
  ```

  or

  ```
  By by = By.xpath("//*[contains(., 'Single contact')]");
  ```

  or if `id` is not dynamically generated

  ```
  By by = By.id("select2-contact_id-result-v0w5-258");
  ```
- May be your element is inside a `frame` or `iframe`, If it is then you need to switch that `frame` or `iframe` before finding element as below :-

  ```
  driver.switchTo().frame("frame id or name or index");
  ```
- May be element is not being fully loaded on the page due to slow internet, so you need to implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until element is visible and clickable as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 10);
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by)); //use anyone of the above by object
  ```

Now after successfully getting element you need to perform `click` as below :-

```
el.click();
```

**Note** :- if your element is actually a dropdown with `select` tag, then you need to create `Select()` object to work with dropdown as below :-

```
Select sel = new Select(el);

//now perform step to select an option by visible text from dropdown 
sel.selectByVisibleText("your visible option text");
```

or

```
sel.selectByIndex("your option index");
```

or

```
sel.selectByValue("your option value");
```

Hope it helps you..:)

Comment: Actualy xpath was changing its value whenever we click on the element. i used wild card for thatdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(@id, 'select2-contact_id-result-')]") ).click();

Comment: @niazi..yeah as I say your id looks like dynamically generated...so this one also is a best `xpath` to locate...:)

Comment: @niazi but i'm suggesting you give the priority `By.className` or `By.cssSelector` first... if not success then try with `xpath`...because using `xpath` is slower than other locator to locate an element..:)